# Magento 2 variables

Tags: magento2

Google team share with me a script for tracking and they asked me to put magento 2 variables.
I've searched about and this is the script after update but I think it's not correct.

```
<script>
  dataLayer.push({
    'event':'purchase',
    'order_value':$order->getGrandTotal(),
    'order_id':$order->getOrderId(),
    'enhanced_conversion_data': {
      "email": $customer_email,   
      "phone_number": $telephone_tmp,
      "first_name": $firstname,
      "last_name": $lastname,
      "street": $address_tmp,
      "city": $city,
      "postal_code": $postal,
      "country": $country
    }
  })
</script>
```

Could you please help me.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding this into your success.phtml template, you may want to consider using a GTM extension. eg https://github.com/magepal/magento2-google-tag-manager

Answer (score 0):

I have this code as following in my success.phtml. Take a look.

```
<script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
  dsDataLayer.push({
    'event':'purchase',
    'order_value': <?php echo json_encode($order->getGrandTotal()) ?>,
    'order_id':<?php echo json_encode($block->getOrderId()) ?>,
    'enhanced_conversion_data': {
      "email": <?php echo json_encode($order->getCustomerEmail()) ?>,   
      "phone_number": <?php echo ($billingAddress->getTelephone() ? json_encode($billingAddress->getTelephone()) : '""'); ?>,
      "first_name": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getFirstName()) ?>,
      "last_name": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getLastName()) ?>,
      "street": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getStreet()[0]) ?>,
      "city": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getCity()) ?>,
      "region": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getRegion()) ?>,
      "postal_code": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getPostcode()) ?>,
      "country": <?php echo json_encode($billingCountry) ?>
    }
  })
   /* ]]> */
</script>



<script>
  var enhanced_conversion_data = {
    "email": <?php echo json_encode($order->getCustomerEmail()) ?>,
    "phone_number": <?php echo ($billingAddress->getTelephone() ? json_encode($billingAddress->getTelephone()) : '""'); ?>,
    "first_name": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getFirstName()) ?>,
    "last_name": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getLastName()) ?>,
    "home_address": {
      "street": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getStreet()[0]) ?>,
      "city": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getCity()) ?>,
      "region": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getRegion()) ?>,
      "postal_code": <?php echo json_encode($billingAddress->getPostcode()) ?>,
      "country": <?php echo json_encode($billingCountry) ?>
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
    'send_to': 'AW-1006200248/kMXwCJ2asf7987a98sdf7',
    'value': <?php echo json_encode($order->getGrandTotal()) ?>,
    'currency': 'CAD',
    'transaction_id': <?php echo json_encode($block->getOrderId()) ?>
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Dear, it's should be in the top ? or anywhere ?

Comment: Anywhere on the page, assuming your gtag/gtm tags are already loaded.

Comment: I'm facing a problem now, the scripts are not loaded ! While I've already added it it success.phtml